# How to use terminal services programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I want to access remote server using my program (C# .NET) and execute there a program in the context of connected user, just like using Remote Desktop.

I don't want just run a program using some user account(like RunAs), but to have a separate execution session like Remote Desktop

I guess terminal services should be used somehow, but I don't know exactly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out this open source project: http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals
It uses Terminal Services ActiveX Client (mstscax.dll) to do a lots of interesting things.

Just download the project and check out the source, Im sure it will give you all information you need to do what you want.